# nginx config with angular4 application and wordpress blog on one of the route

Tags: php, wordpress, angular, nginx, centos7

> Assumption:

Application is running on https://example.com [which is static serving from /home/centos/projects/dist.example.com]

I am trying to run https://example.com/blogs to serve wordpress blog application.

> Below is my nginx config

```
    server {
    server_name example.com;

    root /home/centos/projects/dist.example.com;
    index  index.html;

    access_log /home/centos/log/example/access.log;
    error_log /home/centos/log/example/error.log;

    location / {
       try_files $uri /index.html;
       expires -1;
       add_header  Cache-Control public;
    }

    location /download {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7000/api/downloads/;
    }

    location /blogs {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blogs/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php = 404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
         }
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    ##
    # `gzip` Settings
        #
    #
    gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level    6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_min_length    256;
        gzip_types
            application/atom+xml
            application/javascript
            application/json
            application/rss+xml
            application/vnd.ms-fontobject
            application/x-font-ttf
            application/x-web-app-manifest+json
            application/xhtml+xml
            application/xml
            font/opentype
            image/svg+xml
            image/x-icon
            text/css
            text/plain
            text/javascript
            text/x-component;
}
```

I am running my nginx as root and centos linux set on permissive mode. 
I am successfully able to run the example.com but when i try to run example.com/blogs it gives nginx error 403 forbideed

> below is the part of my php-fpm conf

```
user = centos
; RPM: Keep a group allowed to write in log dir.
group = centos

;listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen = /var/run/php-fpm.sock

listen.owner = root
listen.group = root
;listen.mode = 0660
```

I am not getting where i am facing issue with permission

Comment: what are the permissions and ownership of `/home/centos/projects/dist.example.com/blog` ??

Comment: centos is the ownership of /home/centos/projects/dist.example.com/blog

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer to this problem

```
  location  /blog { 
     resolver 8.8.8.8; 
     proxy_pass https://betablog.example.com;
     if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ){
        return 444;
    }
  }
```

Also make a config change in wp-config.php change the site name to http://example.com/blogs